# Animate TableView Cell to swipe left

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I would like to make a simple animation in the first cell of a table view to indicate that the user can delete this cell!

I have already completed the delete feature of the cell, etc.

How is it possible to achieve this like a bounce animation?

Facebook has already done that if you go to the notifications for the very first time you go to that view.

Comment: I don't think facebook app uses Apple default swipe actions. They are using custom created action buttons when swiped. SO they can animate any way they like. I don't think that it is possible to do what you asked with default apple swipe action. If you want you can check other ways instead of apple default delete button behavior. There are lot of pods/libs available.

Comment: @RJE i've seen some pods, but i just asked in case i miss any function in swift that can make a cell animate swipe left action :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can take one view inside cell. Design it whatever way you like.

2) Set it frames like it want be visible on screen while designing.

3) To adding animation effect, you can use default UIView animation or you can refer UIKit dynamics to achieve spring and bouns effect.

4) Set view frames progamatically to come from right to left.

4) Rest of the logic to display only one time, you can write it by yourselef :-)

Comment: Made an extensive search before i post it here and i thought too that this should be a possible way, but i always ask in case i miss any function of swift. So i guess there is no possible way with the built in functions to animate a swipe left. Ok then thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome buddy. Happy coding :-)